# block ad from uiwebview (iOS)

Tags: ios, uiwebview

My app loads a page from a site where there are ads. 
I am looking for a way to block, to ensure that they do not appear.
On android you can block it, but on iOS? Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

While looking at the [`UIWebViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) to see what methods are available, I noticed a link to the Apple sample app [`CustomHTTPProtocol`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CustomHTTPProtocol/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013653) which shows how to intercept the underlying networking performed by the web view (I haven't looked at the code however).

I believe this is the approach to use, and you need to ignore any requests to sites you don't want to allow.